# I can't change TableCell border color in material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, border

I have a problem with changing the border color of table cell.
I've tried many times but it doesn't work.
please help me.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      root: {
        borderBottom: '1px solid #ff0000',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I tried above theme to table. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 MuiTableCell: {
  styleOverrides: {
    head: {
       borderBottom:"1px solid red"
    },
    body: {
       borderBottom:"1px solid blue"
    },
    footer: {
       borderBottom:"1px solid yellow"
    },
  }
}
```